# JDBC - "Greater Than operator (>) " Doesn't work

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

Take a look:

```
     String Pedidos = " select account_order_id , fk_account_id , order_created" +
             " from account_order " +
             " where order_created >= '2014-01-01 00:00:00' ";                      

      try {             
            stmt = siteConn.createStatement();              
             rs2 = stmt.executeQuery(Pedidos);

             List <Pedido> pedidos = new ArrayList <Pedido> () ;
             System.out.println(Pedidos);
             System.out.println(rs2.next());
            while (rs2.next()){
```

My resultSet.next() its returning False despite the fact that there is a thousands results for this...

When i change the operator to "Less Than (<)" it runs without any trouble !!

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: I seriously doubt that the ">" operator does not work.  Did you take your sql string and try to execute is as-is in a query tool of some sort?

Comment: of course i did it man ! I executed it in workbench, result : 49657 row(s) returned...

Comment: I would guess that the actual values in `order_created` don't look anything like "2014-01-01 00:00:00", and since you gave the DB no hints that that column is a date, it doesn't do any implicit mapping for you.

Comment: @user3609798 This is probably a stupid thing to try, but what happens if you use the compete format `'2014-01-01 00:00:00.000'` (time changed)? (this kinda joins @pohart's answer, where he specifies the date format).

Comment: can you see the DB log of the query that gets executed via JDBC?

Comment: I DID IT GUYS !!!
 
Sorry for bother but the error was in my connection !!

I was using the an old database, this is why there is no results after 2014...

Thanks guys !

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what database you are using but I would guess the problem is with your date. Your sql client might be setting a session variable that changes the expected format for dates.

In oracle I would do this:

```
String Pedidos = " select account_order_id , fk_account_id , order_created" +
                 " from account_order " +
                 " where order_created >= to_date('2014-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')";
```

In other DBs you use different functions:

- sqlserver uses convert
- mysql uses str_to_date
- postgres uses to_date

Comment: I DID IT GUYS !!!
 
Sorry for bother but the error was in my connection !!

I was using the an old database, this is why there is no results after 2014...

Thanks anyway !